# Why my class instance is of type int (I can't access its attributes)?

Tags: python, abstract-methods

I have created a class in Python that has only abstract methods, and then implemented all the methods in the class `BasicMR` (not all the code of `BasicMR` is present in the snippet, but the method `test_stationary()` is called inside `self.generate_positions()`):

```
class Strategy(object):
    __metaclass__=ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def generate_positions(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must implement generatePositions()!")

    @abstractmethod
    def get_positions(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must implement getPositions()!")


class BasicMR(Strategy):
    def __init__(self, security, lookback=30):
        self.__securities = []
        self.__securities = security   # it could be either one security or a list of security objects
        self.__positions = self.generate_positions()

    def test_stationary(self, lb=30):
        if not isinstance(self.__securities, list):
            securities = [self.__securities]
        else:
            securities = self.__securities
        prices = [one_stock.get_prices(lb) for one_stock in securities]  # list comprehension
        results = [ts.adfuller(price_series, regression="c", autolag='AIC') for price_series in prices]
        simple_results = [BasicMR.simplify_adf_results(result[1], result[0], result[4]) for result in results]
        if len(simple_results) == 1:
            return simple_results[0]
        else:
            return simple_results

    def generate_positions(self, long_only=False, time_frame=20, max_holding_period = 20):
        result = []
        names = []
        # HERE IS SOME CODE
        return [names, result]

    def get_positions(self):
        return self.__positions
```

However, when I create an instance of `BasicMR()`, I get an error on this line:

```
if not isinstance(self.__securities, list):
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_BasicMR__securities'
```

Somehow, my BasicMR class instance is recognized as type `int`, and I don't know what to do with that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `test_stationary` **on the class**:

```
>>> BasicMR.test_stationary(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 20, in test_stationary
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_BasicMR__securities'
```

This passes in `42` as the `self` argument because the method isn't bound.

You cannot *create* an instance of the class because you didn't provide concrete implementations for `generate_positions` and `get_positions` however:

```
>>> BasicMR([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 6, in generate_positions
NotImplementedError: You must implement generatePositions()!
```

Comment: But the problem is that BasicMR class has generate_positions() method implemented (there are lots of lines of code so I didn't copy that in my question's code snippet). But the thing is that generate_positions() in BasicMR has several parameters, and in the abstract class it doesn't have any. Could that be a problem? I still don't understand why test_stationary() isn't bound...

Comment: @OlegLukianchikov: You never gave us a minimal example with which to reproduce your problem, so I had to make some assumptions. You'll need to show us more code that at least demonstrates how you are using the object. Abstract method signatures are not validated, it doesn't matter what arguments `generatePositions()` takes in the implementation, only that it is there at all.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's much more confusing without actual code. But the thing is that your answer about the method being not bound let me find the issue in how I declared the methods. At first I was thinking that there must be some trick with abstract methods in Python. So, I appreciate your answer a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the source of the problem. In the method `generate_positions()` I called instance' method as if it's a class method, that is instead of writing

```
stationarity_checked_securities = self.test_stationary(time_frame)
```

I had:

```
stationarity_checked_securities = BasicMR.test_stationary(time_frame)
```

And the `test_stationary()` was defined as:

```
def test_stationary(self, lb=30):
    #some code here
```

That is, it is not a class method, but I called it as if it is. 
In the end, my bug appeared to be quite a simple one, but I was confused by the error text (I am new to Python and I couldn't understand why my class instance was referred to as "`int object`" in the error.

Comment: This is why you should always include the *full traceback* of Python errors. It'd have shown me immediately where you were calling the method unbound. :-)